# Airflow Celery Worker celery-hostname

Tags: celery, airflow

On airflow 2.1.3, looking at the documentation for the CLI, `airflow celery -h`
it shows:

```
-H CELERY_HOSTNAME, --celery-hostname CELERY_HOSTNAME
                        Set the hostname of celery worker if you have multiple workers on a single machine
```

I am familiar with Celery and I know you can run multiple workers on the same machine. But with Airflow (and the celery executor) I don't understand how to do so.

if you do, on the same machine:

```
> airflow celery worker -H 'foo'
> airflow celery worker -H 'bar'
```

The second command will fail, complaining about the pid, so then:

```
> airflow celery worker -H 'bar' --pid some-other-pid-file
```

This will run another worker and it will sync with the first worker BUT you will get a port binding error since airflow binds the worker process to http://0.0.0.0:8793/ no matter what (unless I missed a parameter?).

It seems you are not suppose to run multiple workers per machines... Then my question is, what is the '-H' (--celery-hostname) option for? How would I use it?

Answer (score 0):

The port that celery listens to is also configurable - it is used to serve logs to the webserver:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-log-server-port

You can run multiple celery workers with different settings for that port or run them with `--skip-serve-logs` to not open the webserver in the first place (for example if you send logs to sentry/s3/gcs etc.).

BTW. This sounds strange by the way to run several celery workers because you can utilise the machine CPUS by using parallelism. This seems much more practical an easier to manage.

Comment: Well, the question is about a specific CLI setting that seem to indicate running multiple workers on the same machine is possible and how to use it. I guess using --skip-serve-logs would take care of the binding issue (changing the port won't: the first instance would bind to it, the second would still fail) but then... no logs. In my experience with Celery, running multiple workers is sometimes more efficient than one using all cores. It is documented in the Celery worker documentation: ".... having multiple worker instances running, may perform better than having a single worker. "

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html